# Axios GET request not working in heroku but working in localhost

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, axios

I am using NodeJS and axios.

Within my server, I am simply making a GET request to this API: https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states.

I am getting the data properly in localhost, postman, as well as simple browser request.

But if I deploy it to **HEROKU** and then make the request, it fails with the error 403. But when I make the same request on localhost, it works.

I tried setting the header "User-Agent". It still doesn't work.

The Procfile, process.env.PORT are correctly set.

**This is the actual GET request to be made to my server:**

`https://vac-finder.herokuapp.com/api/sessions/getStates`

**Here's my server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: '*'}))
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/sessions', require('./routes/api/sessions'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on 2000');
});
```

**Here's my actual code (./routes/api/sessions):**

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getStates', (req, res) => {

  const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states`,
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36"
    }
  };

  axios(config)
  .then((response) => {
    res.json({data: response.data.states});
  })
  .catch((error) => {
        res.json({
          errorMessage: 'There has been an error in getting data. Please try after some time.',
          error: error 
        });
  });

})

module.exports = router;
```

**Here's the error response (from HEROKU):**

```
"error": {
        "message": "Request failed with status code 403",
        "name": "Error",
        "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 403\n    at createError (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)\n    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)",
        "config": {
            "url": "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states",
            "method": "get",
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "User-Agent": "axios/0.21.1"
            },
            "transformRequest": [
                null
            ],
            "transformResponse": [
                null
            ],
            "timeout": 0,
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "maxBodyLength": -1
        }
    }
```

Why is this happening?

This is my first question on Stack Over Flow. Suggestions on framing the question better are very welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like the API is just down right now. It answers all my requests with the same 403: Forbidden error, even from Postman or the browser.

Comment: @Jotha Hey, thank you very much for the kind response. I hope you tested THIS API: (https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states)? Because it works for me on postman or browser. I did not face any error. :)